# Disable reboot/shutdown confirmation

Tags: lubuntu, shutdown, reboot

I am running Lubuntu 20. I am trying to disable the reboot confirmation dialog. Based on my research, you can do so using gconf and dconf editors, but the setting is not in either one of them. I also tried running

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session suppress-logout-restart-shutdown true
```

but I get the error

```
No such schema “com.canonical.indicator.session
```

and I wasn't able to find a solution for this error either. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try toggling:

menu | preferences | LSQt Settings | Session Settings | Ask for Confirmation To Leave Session

(I used this to allow me to suspend without confirming)

There's also a useful toggle for 'Lock screen before suspending/hibernating'

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 20.04 and derivatives, you can reboot and poweroff as a normal user with the terminal commands `reboot`, and `poweroff` or `shutdown`. You could thus create a launcher that executes one of these commands, or bind these commands to shortcut keys to reboot/shutdown without confirmation. Make sure that launcher or the shortcut key is not too easy to reach, or you regularly may find yourself unexpectedly thrown out of your system.

Comment: That's a good workaround, I'll give the launcher a shot, thank you.